# CouchbaseLite Inverse Relationship not working

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

I tried putting this off for as long as I could, but I'm really stuck here.

I'm trying to utilize [Inverse Relationships](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/wiki/Inverse-Relationships)

Basically my scheme looks like this:

```
class Album
var artist: artist?

class Artist
@NSManaged var albums:NSArray?
class func albumsInverseRelation() -> String { return "artist" }
class func albumsItemClass() -> AnyClass { return Album.self }
```

Then later I try to access the computed property, `albums`

```
bgdb.modelFactory?.registerClass("Album", forDocumentType: "Album")
bgdb.modelFactory?.registerClass("Artist", forDocumentType: "Artist")

if let artistID = artist?.document?.documentID, let fetchedArtist = try! Artist.fetchOne(field: "_id", operand: .Matches, value: artistID as AnyObject, database: bgdb) {
   print(fetchedArtist.albums as! [Album])
}
```

But `fetchedArtist.albums` returns an empty array!

This is why I'm confused, from debugging:

```
(lldb) po album?.artist?.document?.documentID
▿ Optional<String>
  - some : "-obO5dJTBF-xu4lzbWTM9yU"


(lldb) po fetchedArtist.document?.documentID
▿ Optional<String>
 - some : "-obO5dJTBF-xu4lzbWTM9yU"
```

As it appears, there is an Album that has an Artist ID
and I can also match that Artist ID with an existing Artist

Yet when I ask the `artist` instance for it's `albums`, it fails to return the Album that has the same `artist` ID

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Sweet baby ...

Biggest waste of a few hours I've had in a while

in my code where I was setting the `artist` property

`albumInstance.artist = artistInstance`

it set the model, and everything seemed fine...

But I wasn't calling
`albumInstance.save()` right after...

So at runtime, I could see that `albumInstance.artist` had the right document ID, but without `save()`, the inverse relationship can't work.

yeah... doing that fixed everything...